# Visualizing 3D full/solid body (like full layer) in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I am trying to present layer and simulated layer (how it decreased in a year, for example) in ArcScene, but showing two layers one on each other with a slight difference (like max 30 cm) does not look really great.

I tried to show the difference, but taking the heights from properties it again makes it just a layer surface, not a full body.

Is there a possibility to visualize a layer in ArcScene as a body for which you can choose the upper heights (like elevation) and the inner heights (like for ex. mean sea level or so..)?

The talk goes about Extruding, just stupidly I cannot find such option.

For illustrating. Two colorful layers (impossible to see two) represent lets say 2010 and 2011 and the difference in between them I just made a separate layer (in greyscale). And the properties box in which there is no tab 'Extrude'.

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you are trying to do from your description but have your tried extruding your data - this will give you a solid object (which is what I guess you mean by 'body').

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the question, that indeed what I want to do. Extrude. Just I cannot find such options.. in a place as explained in Esri helpfiles.

Comment: It looks like you are using multiple raster layers.  Normally you would have a single raster or TIN to represent the terrain and then layer vector data on top.  That is why you don't see an 'Extrusion' tab in the layer properties dialog box.  It is only available for vectors.  Much will depend on how amenable your data are to converting to vectors whether that is the way to go.  If you must stick with rasters then your only option is to look at making one layer semi transparent (but that won't give you the solid body you want).

Comment: @SylvesterSneekly thanks for clarification! Indeed forgot about those Extrusion options.. Just would like to stick to raster. But indeed it has to be geometrical - any kind of solid body, so probably will have to try to play around with vectors

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Subsurface Analyst toolset](http://www.aquaveo.com/subsurface-analyst), part of the Arc Hydro Groundwater toolbox. It allows to build 3D GeoVolumes and visualize them in ArcScene ([see video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvQ3XOMfVls)).

Another way to create 3D geological solid is decribed [in this paper](http://www.ags.gov.ab.ca/publications/INF/PDF/INF_136.PDF), requiring XTools Pro.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! The Subsurface looks pretty attractive to try! And also XTools Pro - never heard about!